# How do I define messages for checkboxes that are dynamically generated?

Tags: elm

How do I define messages for checkboxes that are dynamically generated?

```
topicTocheckbox : Topic -> Html Msg
topicTocheckbox topic =
    div []
        [ input [ type_ "checkbox", name "topic", onClick TopicSelected, value <| getTopic topic ] []
        , label [] [ text <| getTopic topic ]
        ]
```

It would be easier for me to pattern-match on the attached data of a message. In my case, I would attach the topic to the TopicSelected union case.

Hence, I wish I could define a message like this:

```
type Msg
    = TopicSelected topic
```

However, that doesn't align with the [example that I am referencing](http://elm-lang.org/examples/checkboxes).

Here's how the checkboxes are being generated:

```
topicsUI : List Topic -> Html Msg
topicsUI topics =
    let
        formattedTopics =
            topics |> List.map topicTocheckbox
    in
        Html.form [ action "" ] formattedTopics
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `TopicSelected` a parameter. In the example you linked, you referenced this `Msg` definition:

```elm
type Msg
  = ToggleNotifications
  | ToggleAutoplay
  | ToggleLocation
```

You could rewrite this as a single `Toggle` msg with a `Target` type:

```elm
type Target
  = Notifications
  | Autoplay
  | Location

type Msg
  = Toggle Target
```

Then you can pattern match in `update` by each variation:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Toggle Notifications ->
      { model | notifications = not model.notifications }

    Toggle Autoplay ->
      { model | autoplay = not model.autoplay }

    Toggle Location ->
      { model | location = not model.location }
```

The view for this new definition in the beginnerProgram example looks like this:

```elm
checkbox (Toggle Notifications) "Email Notifications"
```

This translates well to your `Topic` example. Depending on how `Topic` is defined, you could do this:

```elm
type Topic
    = Math
    | Literature
    | Music

type Msg
    = TopicSelected Topic
```

Your `onClick` could look like this:

```elm
onClick (TopicSelected topic)
```

and your update could specify each topic by pattern matching:

```elm
update msg model =
  case msg of
    TopicSelected Math ->
      model

    TopicSelected Literature ->
      model
    ...
```